# Weird behavior in onBackPressed with respect to Android Kitkat and Lollipop

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Am observing different weird onBackPressed behavior with respect to Android kitkat and lollipop.

In a fragment, a value is added to radioButton and an option to move to the next screen. After moving to the next screen and pressing backButton, expectation is that control goes back to the previous screen along with populated value in radioButton should appear.

**Android kitkat**

Its working as expected, where navigating to the previous screen via backButton restores the value to be populated in radioButton. No issues.

**Android Lollipop**
Its not working as expected, rest of the fragment is loaded while the value to be populated in the radioButton remains empty text.

Following is the code segment.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    // ...
}
```

Should onBackPressed() be treated differently between the two flavours?

Any pointers on how to debug?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have custom behaviour for `onBackPressed()` method, try to move `super.onBackPressed()` to the end of your overloaded `onBackPressed()` method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Tried that, no change, still the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this simple trick:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    getActivity().finish();
}
```

Remove getActivity() if you are writing this in an activity.

Comment: Why should finish be called? Can you please explain? I don't want the activity to close.

Comment: Don't you want to go to the previous screen when pressing the back button? If yes, this code will force the app to do that. If I misunderstood your question, please tell me what you need exactly.

Comment: I have a single activity and from there the control navigates to various fragments. So with onBackPressed() it should only take to the previous state in the stackTrace and not close the activity. Please do let me know if I have to provide any other information.

Comment: Do you mean you use a ViewPager or something similar?

Comment: Not a ViewPager. In the mainActivity, callbacks for all the interfaces defined in various fragments are implemented in the activity. Whenever there is an action in fragment, corresponding interface is called for which the implementation is there in the mainActivity. Based on the input it just navigates to various fragments.

The whole to and fro works fine in kitkat but not in lollipop.